# подсчет гласных и согласных при условии, что в строке могут содержаться буквы кириллицы в нижнем регистре и пробелы

Tags: java

Добра! мне нужно подсчитать количество гласных и согласных букв, при условии, что в строке могут содержаться буквы кириллицы в нижнем регистре и пробелы. сам смог написать лишь такую околесицу, буду благодарен если поможете

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = in.nextLine();
    String[] strr = str.split("");

    var glas = "йуеыаоэяию";
    var sogl = "цкнгшщзхъфвпрлджчсмтьб";

    String[] glass = glas.split("");
    String[] sogll = sogl.split("");

    int count_q = 0; int vount_s = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = strr.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            System.out.println(strr[i]);

            if (strr[i] == glass[i]) count_q++;
            if (strr[i] == sogll[i]) vount_s++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count_q + " " + vount_s);
```

Comment: и что же не так с этой околесицей?

Comment: Что такое var? Вы коллекции уже изучали? С ними выйдет код  лучше (быстрее и компактней).

Comment: *мне нужно подсчитать количество гласных и согласных букв* Просто считаешь разницу длин исходной строки и строки, в которой соотв. буквы заменены на пустую строку. Заменять - регуляркой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, что хэшсетами вам пользоваться запрещено, а считать количества гласных и согласных всё-таки надо.  Идея воспользоваться вложенными циклами в принципе верна, проблема только в том, что в Java *нельзя* в общем случае сравнивать *строки* при помощи оператора `==`, а вот символы можно.

Также можно заменить внутренний цикл, проверяющий гласные буквы, на стандартный метод `String::indexOf`, возвращающий -1, если символ не был обнаружен.

Если входные данные *гарантированно* содержат только *русскую кириллицу в нижнем регистре и пробелы*, для определения типа букв достаточно использовать только строку с гласными, отсортированными по убыванию [их частоты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C):

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = in.nextLine().toLowerCase(); // гарантировать нижний регистр

String vowels = "оеаиуяыюэё";

int cons = 0, vows = 0;

for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        continue;         // пропустить пробелы
    }
    if (vowels.indexOf(c) != -1) {  // найдена гласная
        vows++;
    } else { // иначе согласная
        cons++;
    } 
}
System.out.println("Гласных: " + vows + "; coгласных: " + cons);
```

Для "ускорения" вместо `String::indexOf` можно воспользоваться оператором `switch`:

```java
//...
    if (c == ' ') {
        continue;         // пропустить пробелы
    }
    switch (c) {
        case 'о','е','а','и','у','я','ы','ю','э','ё' -> vows++;
        default -> cons++;
    }
```

---

Пример с использованием хэшсета для гласных, и Stream API, в частности `Collectors.partitioningBy` для разбиения букв на гласные/согласные и `Collectors.summingInt` / `Collectors.counting` для подсчёта частот букв определённого вида:

```java
static void printStats(String str) {
    var vowels = Set.of('о','е','а','и','у','я','ы','ю','э','ё');
    var counts = str.toLowerCase()
        .chars()
        .filter(c -> c != ' ')
        .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
            vowels::contains, Collectors.summingInt(x -> 1)
        ));
    System.out.println("Гласных: " + counts.get(true) + "; coгласных: " + counts.get(false));
}
```

---

Вариант с удалением ненужных символов при помощи `String.replaceAll` и наборов символов:

```java
static void printStats2(String str) {
    // оставить русскую кириллицу
    String letters = str.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^а-яё]+", "");
    // убрать гласные
    String cons = letters.replaceAll("[оеаиуяыюэё]", "");

    System.out.println("Гласных: " + (letters.length() - cons.length()) + "; coгласных: " + cons.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше конечно же разбивать по словам, а не искать во всей строке.

```
String inString="Труффальдино из Бергамо"; 
List russainVowels = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('А', 'Е', 'Ё', 'И', 'О', 'У', 'Ы', 'Э', 'Ю', 'Я', 'а', 'е',
            'ё', 'и', 'о', 'у', 'ы', 'э', 'ю', 'я'));
List russainСonsonants = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList('Б', 'В', 'Г', 'Д', 'Ж', 'З', 'Й', 'К', 'Л', 'М', 'Н',
            'П', 'Р', 'С', 'Т', 'Ф', 'Х', 'Ц', 'Ч', 'Ш', 'Щ', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'ж', 'з', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н',
            'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ь'));
List total =   inString.chars().mapToObj(e->(char)e).collect(Collectors.toList());
total.retainAll(russainVowels);//для длясных, для  согласных   подставить russainСonsonants 
int result = total.size();
```

Comment: А чем лучше разбивать на слова текст? Отдельные слова - такие же отдельные строки, итераций будет больше вот и вся разница.

Comment: Лучше использовать HashSet - ведь поиск по HashSet будет сложность О(1), а по List O(n)